# Why is a change in dipole moment a prerequisite for detection of a molecule by IR spectroscopy

Tags: spectroscopy

Why does a molecule need to have asymmetric vibration modes that encompass a variation in its dipole moment in order to be detected by IR spectroscopy?

Answer (score 1):

In short: a changing (oscillating) electric dipole moment will emit radiation that can be picked up by a detector. No change in dipole, no radiation, nothing detected.

Comment: In other words, is the oscillating dipole that absorbs, not the vibration itself (which of course is present independently of the IR radiation).

Comment: @Alchimista In the semiclassical treatment of absorption spectroscopy, absorption is measured as destructive interference between the incident light and the radiation emitted by the induced oscillating dipole.

Comment: absorption _is the _result_  of interference between... _. Does it change what is absorbed, or what is absorbing, and especially what is picked up by the detector? That wasn't a comment against your answer, but a comment "in other words". In my opinion is more appropriate as for the detector does not measure any emitted photon, except those from the source, of course.

Comment: And the dipole oscillation is there, is not induced. By the way.